# What is the faster way to Acknowledge Packets and How to avoid loss of packets?

Tags: c#, sockets, time, udp

I am making application in c#. In that application i am receiving data on particular port as

```
UdpClient client = null;
 IPEndPoint ipep = null;
 client = new UdpClient(24097); 
 client.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 25000;
 ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,24097);
while(flag)
{
  byte[] data= = client.Receive(ref ipep);
  SendAck(data);
}

public void SendAck(byte[] data)
{
    //Some code for making ack buffer
socket.SendTo(buffer,endpoint);
}
```

In that application i want to send acknowledgement of received packet manually. But my problem is that within time of making acknowledgement, Some of the data comes and get loss because main thread is busy with making acknowledgment. Please suggest me any other solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "How to avoid loss of packets" - use TCP would be a good start, and offload that concern to the NIC... and ack-ing every packet seems overkill; what is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: My requirement is i have to send acknowledgement is some predefined structure format. So i am not using TCP.Whether is it possible to send ACK manually with TCP?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple, well-documented, battle-tested solution to your problem available, that has been ported to any relevant OS out there: It is called TCP

Comment: Yes i tried TCP but my requirement is that i have to send acknowledgement manually? Whether it is possible with TCP?

Comment: You are talking of two distinct ACK processes: acknowledging the reception of the packet (network layer) and acknowledging with some specially crafted data (application layer). TCP will give you the chance to let the first be handled by the OS, while you do the second manually. Your code will work on TCP without packet loss - it will still be suboptimal, but it will work

Comment: THANKS for reply.Can you elaborate or give some small example of ack packets at network layer and APPLICATION LAYER?

Comment: IFUC all that matters to you is the ACK the other half of your application receives, in this case simply forget the network level ACKs, you'll never see them in your code. If you DO want to know about them, read up on TCP. First try your existing code with TCP and work from there.

Comment: I tried TCP but it sends ack automatically.How i can  control that?

Comment: Again: TCP will send the ACKs for the NETWORK LAYER automatically, but your application will never see them: See it as a OS to OS communication, that doesn't go up to the application. You also can't put any payload in them. You are still free to send your APPLICATION LAYER ACKs however you want.